# Generic interface inheritance Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

First of all i will show my code. I have this generic interface:

**BaseWebserviceCool:**

```
public interface BaseWebserviceCool<I extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, O extends WsRespuestaBaseBean> {

    O create(I wsRequest);  
    O read(I wsRequest);    
    O update(I wsRequest);  
    void delete(I wsRequest);

}
```

**SessionPeticionBean:**

```
public class SessionPeticionBaseBean implements Serializable {  
    private String token;       
    private String uuidUsuarioLogado;

}
```

**WsRespuestaBean:**

```
public class WsRespuestaBaseBean implements Serializable
{
    private String codigoRespuesta;
    private String mensajeRespuesta;
    private boolean error;
    private Map<String, String> errors;
}
```

Getters and setters skipped.
I then have another specific interface that extends the above base interface like that:
**WsPersonasInterface:**

```
public interface WsPersonasInterface<I extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, O extends WsRespuestaBaseBean> 
extends BaseWebserviceCool<I, O>
{


}
```

The point is that my web controller must implement the base interface method through the specific interface (**WsPersonasInterface**). In my controller im doing something like that:

```
public class PersonasController extends BaseController 
    implements BaseWebserviceCool<SessionPeticionBaseBean, WsRespuestaBaseBean>

{

    @RolesAllowed({ "ROLE_USER" })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create/", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    @Override
    public CreatePersonaWsRespuestaBean create(
            @RequestBody @Valid CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean createPersonaPeticionBean) {


        return personasBusiness.createPersona(createPersonaPeticionBean);
    }

    @Override
    public @ResponseBody PersonaWsRespuestaBean read(
            @RequestBody @Valid ReadPersonaWsPeticionBean readPersonaWsPeticionBean) {

        return personasBusiness.readPersona(readPersonaWsPeticionBean);

    }
```

For brevity i skipped the remaining methods. But this implementation/overriding fails..

I my controller, **CreatePersonaWsRespuestaBean and PersonaWsRespuestaBean are  classes that inherits from WsRespuestaBean and CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean and ReadPersonaWsPeticionBean inherits from SessionPeticionBaseBean**.

There is surely a design problem, any smart mind cand give some tips?

Comment: I don't understand why _my web controller must implement the base interface method through the specific interface_.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to replace `implements BaseWebserviceCool<SessionPeticionBaseBean, WsRespuestaBaseBean>` by `implements WsPersonasInterface<CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean, CreatePersonaWsRespuestaBean>`. What's the problem?

Comment: I use interfaces for testing purposes. The "base generic interface" provides the typical CRUD operations but my controller can need some specific operations like "findUserByName" that is not defined in the "Base Interface".

Comment: @JBNizet I added one more method of my controller, hope this way is better for understanting.
Judging your comment, my controller cannot implement "WsPersonasInterface<CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean, CreatePersonaWsRespuestaBean>" then the "READ" method wont either work.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. That makes no sense. Your interface says that the type of the arguments of read() and create() is identical: `I`. Your implementation tries to define read() and create() with two different arguments. That can't work. Something that can read books and create televisions is not something that can read and create the same thing.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that the name classes doesnt help but please read well my question. The type of the arguments of read() and create() inherits from same base class. I think i shoul use java wildcards but im not sure how..

Comment: I have. Your interface says: read and create both take I as argument. Your implementation says: read takes a ReadPersonaWsPeticionBean, but create takes a CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean. So it clearly doesn't match. Either both take a ReadPersonaWsPeticionBean, or both take a CreatePersonaWsPeticionBean, or both take an instance of their common base class as argument. They can't take a different type and implement the interface. A List<Banana> is not a List<Fruit>: you can store any kind of Fruit in a List<Fruit>, but can only store Bananas in a List<Banana>.

Comment: @JBNizet but both method takes a argument of a shared super type. Isn't there any way to say: i want that this interfaces methods takes arguments of a class type that inherits from a base clas??

Comment: There is a way, but I'm not sure what you gain by doing that. Your interface should be a BaseWebserviceCool<I1 extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, I2 extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, I3  extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, I4 extends SessionPeticionBaseBean, O extends WsRespuestaBaseBean>, whereI1 is the type accepted by the read() method, I2 is the type accepted by the create method, etc. Do you really need that interface and those generic types?

Comment: I think you really dont understand what im asking for. I need that interfaces for later testing.

Comment: I don't know if you can change the signature of the method to be overridden? You can do dynamic binding by setting return type as suoer class and inside methid returning subclass

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your controller's methods to respect the contract (your interface `BaseWebserviceCool`) you implement:

```
public class PersonasController extends BaseController 
    implements BaseWebserviceCool<SessionPeticionBaseBean, WsRespuestaBaseBean>

{

    @RolesAllowed({ "ROLE_USER" })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create/", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    @Override
    public WsRespuestaBaseBean create(
            @RequestBody @Valid SessionPeticionBaseBean createPersonaPeticionBean) {


        return personasBusiness.createPersona(createPersonaPeticionBean);
    }

    @Override
    public @ResponseBody WsRespuestaBaseBean read(
            @RequestBody @Valid SessionPeticionBaseBean readPersonaWsPeticionBean) {

        return personasBusiness.readPersona(readPersonaWsPeticionBean);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my little knowledge and understanding of your code , you are trying to implement certain algorithm in your case, create certain type of Object creation. So you can opt for well accepted design patterns like Strategy pattern.
[Strategy Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)